# what permissions does user need to have to use linked server and its default remote user mapping

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, users, remote

i have some linkedserver and for it created default maping that `mapping list` is empty
and all goes thrue 'Be made using this seciurity context'

and this works fine - i can querry this linked from any user that have `sysadmin` role
but when i have user that is `public` only
then i get that failed - 'there is no mapping exists for user x'

how can i fix that? is there some special permission that i need to apply ?
it is MSSQL 2019
scripted linked is:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'PB01_ENC', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'x.x.x.x,9945'@provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'PB01_ENC',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'xxx',@rmtpassword='########'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01_ENC', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
```

others  linked but not encrypted works fine
am i missing something here maybe?

even if i add specyfic mapping for this public user - with password or via impersonate - stil the same :/

please advice
best regards !

Comment: did you check the user has the same perms in both source and destination?

Comment: Yes perms are ok. if it would be not then it would not work when user is sa group. if i script the linked AS the non sa user then it does not see this part @provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;' and also does not see the EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'PB01_ENC',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'xxx',@rmtpassword='########' part . so guess this is the issue here somehow